# CodeCoverage results not showing in Azure DevOps even though .coverage file is created

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to setup code coverage on Azure Piplelines.
I enabled it in the YAML file and can see that the .coverage file is created but it doesn't show the details in the CodeCoverage tab in Azure DevOps.
I believe it needs an html file to be generated. My project is in C#.

My yaml file has the following test tasks.

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    codeCoverageEnabled: true
    runSettingsFile: 'src/ProjectName.runsettings'
```

Here is the result:
[image: Azure Devops screenshot]

Can someone provide some guidance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> CodeCoverage results not showing in Azure DevOps even though .coverage file is created

This is a [known issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/662921/code-coverage-report-display-blank.html) on Azure devops. Now, we could only download the report.

**Azure devops only support the download link for `.coverage` files currently. The white page you see is a UI glitch. This scenario is only supposed to render a download link to the coverage file.**

Besides, it has been submitted in this earlier suggestion ticket linked here:

[support vstest .coverage "code coverage" build results tab](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/366142/support-vstest-coverage-code-coverage-build-result.html)

This feature request is On Roadmap, I believe it will be released soon, you can follow this thread to know its latest feedback.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I have been having issues since 2 years now. It is a know issue I believe for .NET Projects.

Comment: @Leo-liu-msft Thanks for the quick response. appreciate it.